# Upgrade to Rails 6 broke my ActionMailer test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, actionmailer, mailgun

I used version 5.2.3 and my tests were successful.

Upgraded to version 6.0.0. Specified `config.load_defaults 6.0` and `config.autoloader = :classic`.

Because of this, all tests where `ActionMailer::Base` is used fail.

Example:

```
test "send email" do
    VCR.use_cassette('mailgun api key') do

      ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
      item = items(:saved)
      visit item_path(item)
      click_button "Send"

      assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count
    end
end
```

Error:

```
Expected: 1
  Actual: 0
```

I noticed that `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob` changed to `ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob`.

Maybe the problem is because of this? How then to solve it?

Comment: Would not `ActionMailer.const_set(:DeliveryJob, ::ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob)` somewhere in the initializer help?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Unfortunately not. Still using MailDeliveryJob. [ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried wrapping the call method of sending mail in

```
assert_emails 1 do
  click_button "Send"
end
```

After that, `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` populated correctly.